# How to make uniquely acting buttons within each item of ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, edit, onclicklistener

In my listview, I need each item to have a button icon that works distinctly according to the item that the button is selected in. The view displays values from ArrayLists (populated from SQLite Databases) that are different for each item. The button is essentially an edit option and is present for each item, ***so when the edit button is pressed, only the values from that item are retrieved.***

Here's the XML for each item:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/list_item_header" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_values"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_item_info"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_edit"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_num"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/edit_button_description"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/editing_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

_ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _ - _

How do I implement a listener programmatically so that I can identify which item has been selected?

Comment: please , can you upload your custom adapter for listview too ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own list adapter and set the button an onClick listener.

Another way would be to disable (clickable = false) the button and set an onItemClick listener to listview and by the position parameter decide what to do - here you would loose the pressed state of the button and your entire item view would basically be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You need an onItemClickListener. If you use this method you can fetch the object behind.

Here is an example of such an onItemClickListener

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
            YourItem item = (YourItem) list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
...
```

Since you have this item you can do what ever you want. Maybe start a new fragment / activity and send the object by an intent, to use it.

For that you need to implement an listadapter like `BaseAdapter` which must be set to the listView.

**EDIT:**
Of course you can use the `CursorAdapter` too. Then list listener is quiete the same